# Replace characters within a specific string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with URLs where space is `+` and it needs to be `%20` to work.

For example:

```
http://myserver/abc/this+is+my+document.doc
```

I want it to be:

```
http://myserver/abc/this%20is%20my%20document.doc
```

How to replace `+` with `%20`, but only when the string starts with `http://myserver/abc`? Don't want to replace any other `+`'s in the document.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need to replace `+` symbols in the chunk of non-whitespaces after `http://myserver/abc`, it is possible.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/p9eZfS/1) `(?:http://myserver/abc|\G(?!\A))[^\s+]*\K\+` replace with `%20`?

Comment: We can assume there is whitespace in the beginning and end.

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks, that did the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/p9eZfS/1)

```
(?:http://myserver/abc|\G(?!\A))[^\s+]*\K\+
```

Replace with `%20`

---

How the regex works?

- `(?:http://myserver/abc|\G(?!\A))` matches either `http://myserver/abc` literally, or the previously matched location (`\G` is previously matched location or start of the string and `(?!\A)` prevents `\G` from matching the start of the string)
- `[^\s+]*` matches any character except whitespace and `+` (literally) any number of times
- `\K` resets the match. Any previously consumed characters are excluded from the final match
- `\+` match this character literally

Comment: learnt a lot from your regex and upvoted it too, if you add the `\A ` at the negation group it will still work, I just test it    →  `(?:http://myserver/abc|\G)[^\s+\A]*\K\+` which one your prefer?